# Android AppBarLayout TabLayout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I try to keep the red layout scrolling so that he hides and the TabLayout stays at the top

I need the red layout to fill the height of the round avatar for me. I try to scroll the TabLayout to the top, and the red layout continues to scroll to hide it.？

I can't send pictures, please click on the link to view the demo.

https://shejiao-v2.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/ezgif.com-optimize.gif

This is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_spring_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="95dp"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/default_cover_bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/actionbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:contentInsetStart="?actionBarInsetStart"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_avatar"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/default_avatar"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:civ_border_color="#D6D6D6"
                        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
                        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.CircleImageViewBehavior" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.thsseek.shejiao.ui.widget.CircleImageViewFAB
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/default_avatar"
        app:civ_border_color="#D6D6D6"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.kekstudio.dachshundtablayout.DachshundTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:ddIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I change this to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead LinearLayout for offset just use View.
Move **CircleImageViewFAB(avatar)** and View(offset) in **CollapsingToolbarLayout** after imageView(background) but before **Toolbar**

**Sheme:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        ...>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            ...>

            <!--background image-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                ... />

            <!--big avatar image-->
            <com.thsseek.shejiao.ui.widget.CircleImageViewFAB
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                ... />

            <!-- offset with background for big avatar -->
            <View
                android:id="@+id/offset"
                ... />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/actionbar"
                ... />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.kekstudio.dachshundtablayout.DachshundTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                ... />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```